# IonicPopUp using http.post result data

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

How can i pass data from http.post results to an IonicPopUp?

Inside my http.post success section i do create the alertPopUp function passing result as parameter .

It opens the popup but there is no data to show.

I would to show any data from $scope.result .

Here is the code i do use the sample from http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopup/ :

```
`$scope.showAlert = function(result) {

 var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({

    title: 'Detais',
    template: 'Details : 1. {{result}} 2. {{state}} {{result.vehicle_brand}} 2. {{scope}}'
 });
 alertPopup.then(function(res) {
     console.log('Thank you for not eating my delicious ice cream cone');
 });
};`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This maybe the issue of object's property access when you received the `result` object.

Try the following code from your $http.post success callback function. Try to print out the structure of that result like this snippet:

```
$http.post(url).then(function(result){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
});
```

I think its structure maybe something like this:

```
{
  "data": //Your result should be available here!
       { "vehicle_brand": { "a": "b" } },       
  "status": 200,
  "config": { 
      "method": "POST",
      ...
  }
  "statusText": "OK" } 
}
```

Then you can passing it to your ionic popup function like this:

```
$http.post(url).then(function(result){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
    $scope.showAlert(result.data); //Pass the data property as a argument.
});
```